# how to add custom path in URLByAppendingPathComponent in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

In my project I am saving jsondata into local jsonfile named **AllBooking.json**.

Code:

```
NSURL *fileURL =[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"AllBooking.json"];
```

**URLByAppendingPathComponent** method creates this file to any irrelevent path !

And
 **[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]** returns

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

Is there any way that I can give custom path to file ?

Comment: Also add code of [self applicationDocumentsDirectory]

Comment: What you mean by irrelevant path ?

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah I have added the code of [self applicationDocumentsDirectory]

Comment: @MidhunMP It is saved in Documents Directory  which is not found in FINDER !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `URLByAppendingPathComponent` works all fine. Problem would be in your `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method.

I just gave a run for you. Here is how my `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method looks like (assuming you want to return URL for documents directory; however method name must end with URL for clarity):

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:documentsDirectoryPath];
}
```

And this is how I called it:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"AllBooking.json"];
NSLog(@"%@", [fileURL absoluteString]);
```

The log statement correctly prints:

```
/Users/abhinav/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8C8ACA37-0D0F-4FED-A431-BA35EF9F08F1/data/Containers/Data/Application/20B049C0-9A0D-4826-9867-027607D02715/Documents/AllBooking.json
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav It helped ! Got the mistake & solution . Prints the same log .

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped! Could you please accept this answer for the benefit of others.@Bindi